# forloop onclick show textfield

Tags: javascript, php, html

Controller

```
for($x = 1; $x <= $qty; $x++){
    $data .= '<b style="margin-left:10px;">Person ' . $x . '</b>';
    $data .= '<div class="form-group" style="padding-top:10px;">';
    $data .= '  <label for="input-for-age" class="col-sm-2 text-right control-label" style="padding-top:5px;">Age <span class="required">*</span></label>';
    $data .= '  Age: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="AgeCheck" onclick="showCheckbox()">';
    $data .= '  <p id="text" style="display:none; color:red;">Check Enabled</b><br><input type="number" placeholder="Enter Number"></p><br>';
}
```

Below is my javascript

```
function showCheckbox() {
    // Get the checkbox
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    // Get the output text
    var text = document.getElementById("text");

    // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        text.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

How do i make it when click check on checkbox it will enable?

> For now if there is 3 "checkbox", i click on 1 checkbox it will show
>   textfield , but if i click on 2nd checkbox from the loop , nothing
>   appear

Comment: please post all the code, I can not see your php code at all

Comment: One unique HTML `id` attribute per page.

Comment: @MaxMuster added my forloop code in question

Comment: @StackSlave what do u mean id per page ?

Comment: I don't see any checkboxes ???

Comment: @Dum $data .= '  Age: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="AgeCheck"  onclick="showCheckbox()">';

Comment: When creating your HTML with PHP, you are  looping over your HTML with the same ids. If you are expecting JavaScript to dynamically access PHP, it doesn't work like that. PHP executes on the Server before code is sent to your Browser. After the first PHP execution, in order to avoid page reloading, use AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you end up having more then one id called myCheck, what is not allowed.

```
for($x = 1; $x <= $qty; $x++){
    $data .= '<b style="margin-left:10px;">Person ' . $x . '</b>';
    $data .= '<div class="form-group" style="padding-top:10px;">';
    $data .= '  <label for="input-for-age" class="col-sm-2 text-right control-label" style="padding-top:5px;">Age <span class="required">*</span></label>';
    $data .= '  Age: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="AgeCheck" onclick="showCheckbox()">';
    $data .= '  <p id="text" style="display:none; color:red;">Check Enabled</b><br><input type="number" placeholder="Enter Number"></p><br>';
}
```

this is why you must add a variable nex to it

```
for($x = 1; $x <= $qty; $x++){
    $data .= '<b style="margin-left:10px;">Person ' . $x . '</b>';
    $data .= '<div class="form-group" style="padding-top:10px;">';
    $data .= '  <label for="input-for-age" class="col-sm-2 text-right control-label" style="padding-top:5px;">Age <span class="required">*</span></label>';
    $data .= '  Age: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck'.$x.'" name="AgeCheck'.$x.'" onclick="showCheckbox('.$x.')">';
    $data .= '  <p id="text'.$x.'" style="display:none; color:red;">Check Enabled</b><br><input type="number" placeholder="Enter Number"></p><br>';
}
```

and in your function you must now add the variable in the same way

```
function showCheckbox(x) {
    // Get the checkbox
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck"+x);
    // Get the output text
    var text = document.getElementById("text"+x);

    // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        text.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot , i wanted to ask why adding (x) make it works  ?

and i have another question , let say : 
if 1 of them i didn't check , how to disable it ? ( not allowing it to send data )

Comment: @greenboxgoolu id's must be unique in a script, so practically your loop creates html code in witch the id (myCheck) is not unique. for this you must create a range: myCheck1, myCheck2 ... etc, and this is created concatenating a variable.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

```
$data .= '  Age: <input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" name="AgeCheck" textid="'.$x.'" onclick="showCheckbox(this)">';
        $data .= '  <p id="text" style="display:none; color:red;">Check Enabled</b><br>
                    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Number" textid="'.$x.'" class="num-text"/>
                    </p><br>';
```

**JS**

```
function showCheckbox(ele) {
  // Get the output text
  var texts = document.getElementsByClassName("num-text");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
for(var i =0; i <texts.length; i++){
   var text = texts[i];
  if (ele.checked == true && text.getAttribute("textid") == ele.getAttribute("textid")){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
}
```

Here I add a custom attribute to both checkboxe and text inputs. With `textid` attribute , You can connect a checkbox with matching text input.